# Unauthorized getting object from firebase database with python

Tags: android, python, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get an object from my production firebase database but I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 147, in get
return self._client.body('get', self._add_suffix())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 93, in body
resp = self.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 769, in request raise ApiCallError(self._extract_error_message(error), error) 
 firebase_admin.db.ApiCallError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://xxxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com/xxxxxx/0k4Xx6fnasdlnkas.json 
Reason: Unauthorized request.
```

I did the same in my development database and it works correctly. 
I thought that permissions rules from firebase database will be the problem, but I deleted all rules from database and I got the same error.

I think that there's something more in firebase that I don't know that makes my following python script crash.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate('deleteUserCredentialsPRO.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'https://xxxxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/'})
toDeleteUrl = db.reference('path-example/0k4Xx6fnasdlnkas')
print toDeleteUrl
print toDeleteUrl.get()
```

The result from first print (toDeleteUrl) is:

```
<firebase_admin.db.Reference object at 0x1064b42d0>
```

The second print, outputs the error wrote above.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: In my case the app worked in debug but after creating the standlaone executalble with PyInstaller it failed, I realized the Project Tree path was wrong, so I corrected that and now it works alright. Also ensure that private-key.json is in the same path